# Failed to compare two elements in the array

Tags: .net, exception, sorting

I have a `List<T>` where `T` is a class that exposes a "Username" property. Username is of a custom type that encapsulates a string. I implemented the `IComparable<T>` interface on this custom type that simply returns

```
this.encapsulatedString.CompareTo(other.encapsulatedString)
```

I defined an `ICollectionView` of the List thus:

```
AllUsers=CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myList);
```

I added a Sortdescription:

```
AllUsers.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Username",ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

On this line the code throws the exception stated in the title. I can sort the list by other means without problem. Where is the exception coming from?

Comment: It is a shame that Microsoft is not able to throw an intelligent and understandable error message. For example "Two Elements in the array could not be compared because the interface IComparable is not implemented."

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The custom type has to implement [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable) as well as [`IComparable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1). It seems the [`SortDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.sortdescription) uses the old fashioned non-generic version of [`CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto).

Answer (score 7):

your answer isn't strictly correct from what I can tell. My objects don't implement IComarable or IComparable at all and they still work fine. I am creating a CollectionViewSource and adding sort descriptions just like you and not getting this error. I was getting the error because the property in the sort description was blank. Once I fixed this everything worked fine without the interface. I suspect maybe you had a property incorrect and it drops back to using IComparable if it can't access the property.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I added a try/catch block inside the Compare function, and displayed the exception Message to the console. If there is a bug inside your compare function, you will get this secondary exception ("Failed to compare two elements...").

My problem was specifically with indexing to position 3 of a string that was "" due to another bug.

Comment: For me this was also caused by an exception inside the Compare function.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the property being sorted on was `object`, and the error was occurring when some of the objects were `int`s and others were `string`s.

I could've implemented `IComparable`, but the usage of the class was really more string geared - I was able to change `object` to `string`, and make sure that all setters using numbers called `.ToString()`, and it was all set from there.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need to implement the non-generic `IComparable`. You can use the Comparer<T> class if you want to implement this interface in a nice generic way :)