# array sort issue C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, compare

Sorry about my bad way of asking earlier. Basically, i am not being able to implemenet Icomparable CompareTo to compare Taxpayer objects based on tax owed ..can someone help me with the icomparable implementatioin of Taxpayer class??

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Taxes
    {
        class Rates
        {
            // Create a class named rates that has the following data members: 
            private int incomeLimit;
            private double lowTaxRate;
            private double highTaxRate;

            public int IncomeLimit  // use read-only accessor.
            { get { return incomeLimit; } }

            public double LowTaxRate // use read-only accessor.
            { get { return lowTaxRate; } }

            public double HighTaxRate // use read-only accessor.
            { get { return highTaxRate; } }

            //A class constructor that assigns default values of limit=30000, low rate = .15 and high rate = .28.
            public Rates()
            {
                int limit = 30000;
                double lowRate = .15;
                double highRate = .28;

                incomeLimit = limit;
                lowTaxRate = lowRate;
                highTaxRate = highRate;
            }

            //A class constructor that takes three parameters to assign input values for limit, low rate and high rate.
            public Rates(int limit, double lowRate, double highRate)
            {

            }

            //  A CalculateTax method that takes an income parameter and computes the tax as follows:
            public int CalculateTax(int income)
            {
                int limit = 0;
                double lowRate = 0;
                double highRate = 0;
                int taxOwed = 0;

                //  If income is less than the limit then return the tax as income times low rate.
                if (income < limit)
                    taxOwed = Convert.ToInt32(income * lowRate);
                //  If income is greater than or equal to the limit then return the tax as income times high rate.
                if (income >= limit)
                    taxOwed = Convert.ToInt32(income * highRate);
                return taxOwed;
            }
        }  //end class Rates

        //  Create a class named Taxpayer that has the following data members:
        public class Taxpayer
        {
            //Social Security number (use type string, no dashes between groups).  Use get and set accessors.
            string SSN
            { get; set; }

            int yearlyGrossIncome // Use get and set accessors.
            { get; set; }

            public int taxOwed  //  Use read-only accessor.
            {
                get { return taxOwed; }
            }

            // **  The Taxpayer class should be set up so that its objects are comparable to each other based on tax owed.
            class taxpayer : IComparable
            {
                public int taxOwed { get; set; }
                public int income { get; set; }

                int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)
                {
                    int returnVal;
                    taxpayer temp = (taxpayer)o;
                    if (this.taxOwed > temp.taxOwed)
                        returnVal = 1;
                    else
                        if (this.taxOwed < temp.taxOwed)
                            returnVal = -1;
                        else
                            returnVal = 0;
                    return returnVal;


                }  // End IComparable.CompareTo
            } //end taxpayer  IComparable class

            //  **The tax should be calculated whenever the income is set.
            //  The Taxpayer class should have a getRates class method that has the following.
            public static void GetRates()
            {
                //  Local method data members for income limit, low rate and high rate.
                int incomeLimit = 0;
                double lowRate;
                double highRate;
                string userInput;

                //  Prompt the user to enter a selection for either default settings or user input of settings.
                Console.Write("Would you like to enter your own values? (enter 0) or would you like to use the default values? (enter 1):  ");

                /*   If the user selects default the default values you will instantiate a rates object using the default constructor
                * and set the Taxpayer class data member for tax equal to the value returned from calling the rates object CalculateTax method.*/
                userInput = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                if (userInput == "1")
                {
                    Rates rates = new Rates();
                    rates.CalculateTax(incomeLimit);
                } // end if

                /*  If the user selects to enter the rates data then prompt the user to enter values for income limit, low rate and high rate, 
                 * instantiate a rates object using the three-argument constructor passing those three entries as the constructor arguments and 
                 * set the Taxpayer class data member for tax equal to the valuereturned from calling the rates object CalculateTax method. */

                if (userInput == "0")
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter the income limit: ");
                    incomeLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Please enter the low rate: ");
                    lowRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Please enter the high rate: ");
                    highRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                    Rates rates = new Rates(incomeLimit, lowRate, highRate);
                    rates.CalculateTax(incomeLimit);

                }  // end if
            }  //end GetRates class



            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //  instantiate an array of five (5) Taxpayer objects.

                string SSN = "0";
                int income = 0;
                int tax = 0;
                int x = 1;
                Taxpayer[] taxArray = new Taxpayer[5];


                //  Implement a for-loop that will prompt the user to enter the Social Security Number and gross income.
                for (x = 1; x < taxArray.Length; x++)
                {
                    taxArray[x] = new Taxpayer();
                    Console.Write("Please enter the Social Security Number for taxpayer {0}:  ", x);
                    taxArray[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine();

                    //SSN = String.Format("{0:000-00-0000}");
                    Console.Write("Please enter the gross income for taxpayer {0}:  ", x);
                    taxArray[x].yearlyGrossIncome = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    Taxpayer.GetRates();

                }  //end for

                //  Implement a for-loop that will display each object as formatted taxpayer SSN, income and calculated tax.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Taxpayer # {0} SSN: {1}, Income is {2:c}, Tax is {3:c}", i, SSN, income, tax);
                } // end for



                //  Implement a for-loop that will sort the five objects in order by the amount of tax owed and then display 
                //each object as formatted taxpayer SSN, income and calculated tax.

                Array.Sort(taxArray);
                Console.WriteLine("Sorted by tax owed");
                for (int i = 0; x < taxArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Taxpayer # {0} SSN: {1}, Income is {2:c}, Tax is {3:c}", i, SSN, income, tax);


                }


            }  //end main
        } //  end Taxpayer class


    }  //end namespace
```

Comment: I am *not* counting or searching this code to find "line 180". Please quote the code in question, or narrow your code down to what's pertinent.

Comment: Where is line 180 and what does the stack trace say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to compare two elements in the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658661/failed-to-compare-two-elements-in-the-array)

Comment: quick tip: delegate the CompareTo to the underlying CompareTo of taxOwed

Comment: Why is this question posted twice with two different titles? Here's the other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873957/implementing-icomparable-on-a-taxpayer-class-to-sort-based-on-taxowed

Answer (score 3):

`Taxpayer` and `taxpayer` are different classes.

Second one implemets `IComparable`, but you have an array of `Taxpayer`

**EDIT:** This is very bad style of naming, because it is very easy to forget the difference between name and Name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to eliminate the private `taxpayer` class from the public `Taxpayer` class and implement `IComparable<Taxpayer>` on the public `Taxpayer` class.

Here is the start of the Taxpayer class:

```
public class Taxpayer : IComparable<Taxpayer>
{
    //Social Security number (use type string, no dashes between groups).  Use get and set accessors.
    string SSN
    { get; set; }

    int yearlyGrossIncome // Use get and set accessors.
    { get; set; }

    public int taxOwed  //  Use read-only accessor.
    {
        get { return taxOwed; }
    }

    #region IComparable<Taxpayer> Members

    int IComparable<Taxpayer>.CompareTo(Taxpayer other)
    {
        if (this.taxOwed > other.taxOwed)
            return 1;
        else
            if (this.taxOwed < other.taxOwed)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
    }

    #endregion

    //  **The tax should be calculated whenever the income is set.
    //  The Taxpayer class should have a getRates class method that has the following.
    public static void GetRates()

    ....
```