# List sort implementation

Tags: vb.net

Have some problems with my list and sorting feature. I create class Variation and Variations. I trade Variations class as collection list of my Variation to separate it. Now when i have create collection i would like to sort by Variation property position, hovever i get error. Can you help me out? Below all necessary information.

Variation class:

```
Public Class Variation

    Property ID As Integer
    Property Name As String
    Property Erstellungsdatum As Date
    Property Position As SByte

    Sub New()
    End Sub

    Sub New(id As Integer)
        _ID = id
    End Sub

    Sub New(id As Integer, name As String)
        _ID = id
        _Name = name
    End Sub
    Sub New(name As String, position As Integer)
        _Name = name
        _Position = position
    End Sub

    Sub New(id As Integer, name As String, position As SByte)
        _ID = id
        _Name = name
        _Position = position
    End Sub
    Sub New(id As Integer, name As String, erstellungsdatum As Date)
        _ID = id
        _Name = name
        _Erstellungsdatum = erstellungsdatum
    End Sub

End Class
```

class Variations:

```
Public Class Variations
    Implements IDisposable
    Implements IComparer(Of Variation)

    Public MyVariationsCollection As List(Of Variation)

    Sub New()
        MyVariationsCollection = New List(Of Variation)
    End Sub

    Public Function AddToCollection(ByVal variation As Variation) As Boolean
        MyVariationsCollection.Add(variation)
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Sub RemoveFromCollection(index As Integer)
        If Not IsNothing(MyVariationsCollection.Item(index)) Then
            MyVariationsCollection.RemoveAt(index)
        End If
    End Sub


    Public Function Compare(x As Variation, y As Variation) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of Variation).Compare
        If x.Position > y.Position Then
            Return 1
        End If

        If x.Position < y.Position Then
            Return -1
        End If
        Return 0
    End Function

End Class
```

in the code i am doing:

```
Private variations As New Variations
 variations.AddToCollection(New BusinessLayer.Variation(Id, Name, StartPosition))
```

now i would like to sort this list by e.g Position which i implemented in Variations and i would like it to be there and not in Variation class as i want trade Variations class as collection of Variation object to separate  if you know what i mean.

however if i do:

```
_variations.MyVariationsCollection.Sort()
```

then i get error:

```
     ---------------------------
    myprog
    ---------------------------
    System.InvalidOperationException: 
You can not compare two elements in the array. ---> System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable element

       w System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)

       w System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.SwapIfGreater(T[] keys, IComparer`1 comparer, Int32 a, Int32 b)

       w System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.DepthLimitedQuickSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 right, IComparer`1 comparer, Int32 depthLimit)

       w System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)

       --- Koniec śladu stosu wyjątków wewnętrznych ---

       w System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)

       w System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)

       w System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Sort(Int32 index, Int32 count, IComparer`1 comparer)

       w Cenea.UserControl1..ctor(Variations variations, Artikel mainArtikel) w C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Cenea\Cenea\UserControl1.vb:wiersz 26

       w Cenea.FrmMain.btnVariationProcees_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) w C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Cenea\Cenea\FrmMain.vb:wiersz 450

       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)

       w DevComponents.DotNetBar.ButtonX.OnClick(EventArgs e)

       w DevComponents.DotNetBar.ButtonX.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)

       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)

       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

       w System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

       w System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)

       w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)

       w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)

       w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)

       w Cenea.ProgStart.main() w C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Cenea\Cenea\ProgStart.vb:wiersz 14
    ---------------------------
    OK   
    ---------------------------
```

**Final solution:**

```
Public Class Variation
    Implements IComparable(Of Variation)
...

  Public Function CompareTo(pother As Variation) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Variation).CompareTo
        Return String.Compare(Me.Position, pother.Position)
    End Function

...
```

Variations :

```
Imports BusinessLayer

Public Class Variations
    Implements IDisposable

    Public collection As List(Of Variation)

    Sub New()
        collection = New List(Of Variation)
    End Sub

    Public Function AddToCollection(ByVal variation As Variation) As Boolean
        collection.Add(variation)
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Sub RemoveFromCollection(index As Integer)
        If Not IsNothing(collection.Item(index)) Then
            collection.RemoveAt(index)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub SortByPosition()
        collection.Sort()
    End Sub

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: Is that the real excpetion message? Show the complete stack trace.

Comment: @TimSchmelter see full error in main post

Comment: maybe Variations class should inherits List(Of Variation) ?

Comment: Then the [unlocalized error](http://unlocalize.com/pl/1609_Failed-to-compare-two-elements-in-the-array.html) is "Failed to compare two elements in the array". Implement also the non-generic [`ICompare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [unlocalized error](http://unlocalize.com/pl/1609_Failed-to-compare-two-elements-in-the-array.html) is "Failed to compare two elements in the array". Implement also the non-generic [`IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.100).aspx).

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.100).aspx) `Array.Sort` uses the non generic `IComparer` interface:

> This interface is used in conjunction with the `Array.Sort` and
>   `Array.BinarySearch` methods. It provides a way to customize the sort
>   order of a collection. See the Compare method for notes on parameters
>   and return value.

Comment: look at my main post "For Tim" i get the same error.

Comment: @JohnDoe: perhaps you need `IComparable` as well as `IComparable<T>`. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658661/failed-to-compare-two-elements-in-the-array

Comment: I am trying to implement also: IComparable and IComparable(Of Variation) but those methods take one argument i think should be two or? Could you be so kind and help me a bit how this should look like to be tested? i am bit mixed.

Comment: @JohnDoe: they only need one because the other is the current instance. You can refer to it via `this` in C# and `Me` in VB.NET.

Comment: ok but how to configure this:     Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo
        Return Me.Compare(obj.???)
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(other As Variation) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Variation).CompareTo
        Return String.Compare(other.Position, Me. ??? )
    End Function

Comment: current instance in this case will not work i think because i am not in Variation class but in Variations. Could you please help me out to fix that?

Comment: @JohnDoe: `Variation` has to implement `IComparable`

Comment: when i implemented   Implements IComparable(Of Variation) into Variation class and did like this seems to be working   Public Function CompareTo(other As Variation) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Variation).CompareTo
        Return String.Compare(Me.Position, other.Position)
    End Function

Comment: but what concerns me is there any way to avoid putting those interfaces directly into Variation class? - From my point of view that was the reason to create Variations class to include list features like sorting, comparising etc.. and to avoit putting them directly into Variation class, now i see i have to do that or am i missing something here? Please see main post how i finally manage it - is there any purpose currently for Variations class to what i mentioned before? Would like to get a concept. Please take a look on "Final solution" at main topic"