# Implicitly convert an object array to an int array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-core, implicit-conversion

I like to convert a class array to an integer array. My `Data` class is like this-

```
public class Data
{
    public int low, high;

    ...................
    ...................

    public static implicit operator int[](Data myClass) 
    {
        int[] arr = {myClass.low, myClass.high};
        return arr;
    }
}
```

In this `class`, I have an [`implicit` operator conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) function so that the class can be converted to an integer array.

I am creating the `Data` class list object and converting the list to `int` 2D array like this-

```
 public int[][] Merge(int[][] intervals) {
    List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

    ............
    ............

    return list.Cast<int[]>().ToArray();
}
```

Then I am getting this error-

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at (wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)
Line 0: System.Linq.Enumerable+&lt;CastIterator&gt;d__34`1[TResult].MoveNext () in &lt;59093ef301a24e5a91cb0295fb832cca&gt;
Line 0: System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1[T].AddRange (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] items) in &lt;59093ef301a24e5a91cb0295fb832cca&gt;
Line 0: System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) in &lt;59093ef301a24e5a91cb0295fb832cca&gt;
Line 0: System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) in &lt;59093ef301a24e5a91cb0295fb832cca&gt;
Line 58: Solution.Merge (System.Int32[][] intervals) in Solution.cs
Line 21: __DriverSolution__.__Helper__ (System.Int32[][] param_1) in __Driver__.cs
Line 37: __Driver__.Main (System.String[] args) in __Driver__.cs
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at (wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)
Line 0: System.Linq.Enumerable+&lt;CastIterator&gt;d__34`1[TResult].MoveNext () in &lt;59093ef301a24e5a91cb0295fb832cca&gt;
Line 0: System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1[T].AddRange (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] items) in &lt;59093ef301a24e5a91cb0295fb832cca&gt;
Line 0: System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) in &lt;59093ef301a24e5a91cb0295fb832cca&gt;
Line 0: System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) in &lt;59093ef301a24e5a91cb0295fb832cca&gt;
Line 58: Solution.Merge (System.Int32[][] intervals) in Solution.cs
Line 21: __DriverSolution__.__Helper__ (System.Int32[][] param_1) in __Driver__.cs
Line 37: __Driver__.Main (System.String[] args) in __Driver__.cs
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think the error is being thrown from the code you provided. The stack trace seems to indicate that you're calling `list.Sort()` somewhere in your merge function, which is what's causing the error. You may need to implement `IComparable` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658749/10601203)

Comment: Please check updated error what I am getting

Answer (score 1):

I guess the exception is not relevant, and was possibly thrown before the code gets to `Cast<int[]>()`, but what I can see is even the code could reach `Cast<int[]>`, there's still `InvalidCastException` error.

Operator is a compiler trick.

```
int[] array = new Data();
```

The above works because the compiler replaces the right operand of `=` with method call to operator method.

```
int[] array = Data.op_Implicit(new Data());
```

When you use `Cast<T>`, you don't have compiler help you doing the above, so the operator won't be called at all.

To be able to cast, you need to use `Select` method and explicitly cast like this:

```
int[][] array = list.Select(x => (int[])x).ToArray();
```

Comment: I need a `int[][]`, not `int[]`

Comment: @AbrarJahin Oops that was a typo, it returns `int[][]` not `int[]`